# Adding the corresponding matching column value to the table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have this dataframe in Image 1. I extract the sum of all the elements of each commodity as in Image 2.
I need to attach the corresponding/Matching "Hs code" to the table. Please help [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add `HS code` to the `groupby` call:

```
df.groupby(['Commodity Description', 'Hs code'])['April, to March, Value(US $)'].sum()
```